# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError with TestNG + Cucumber + Maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-java

I'm trying to use cucumber in my project.But it always shows java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError after run the TestRunner.java.This is how I prepare my pom.xml , TestRunner.java Login.java and Login.feature pages.How can I fix these errors?

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Test</groupId>
<artifactId>Test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

TestRunner.java

```
 package Runner;

 import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
 import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

 @CucumberOptions(
    glue = {"Steps"},
    features = {"src/main/java/Features"}       
    )   

 public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

 
 }
```

Login.java

```
package Steps;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class Login {
@Given("^I have username and password$")
public void i_have_username_and_password() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    System.out.println("Given");
     
}

@When("^I successfully login$")
public void i_successfully_login() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    System.out.println("When");
}

@Then("^I should navigate to the home page$")
public void i_should_navigate_to_the_home_page() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    System.out.println("Then");
}
```

}

Login.feature

```
Feature: Guru 99 Login

Scenario: Login to Guru with valid UN and psw
Given I have username and password
 
When I successfully login

Then I should navigate to the home page
```

Console output

```
 [31mFailed scenarios:[0m
 [31mLogin.feature:3 [0m# Scenario: Login to Guru with valid UN and psw

1 Scenarios ([31m1 failed[0m)
3 Steps ([31m1 failed[0m, [36m2 skipped[0m)
0m0.120s

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:820)
at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)
at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:530)
at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.<init>(LocalizedXStreams.java:50)
at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:37)
at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:29)
at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:21)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at  java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
at ?.Given I have username and password(Login.feature:4)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final   java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens     java.util" to unnamed module @3551a94
at  java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:177)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:171)
at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields.locate(Fields.java:39)
at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter.<clinit>      (TreeMapConverter.java:50)
at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:820)
at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)
at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:530)
at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.<init>(LocalizedXStreams.java:50)
at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:37)
at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:29)
at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
at   cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:21)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

FAILED: feature(Guru 99 Login)
    Runs Cucumber Feature
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:69)
at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:21)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:820)
at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)
at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:530)
at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.<init>   (LocalizedXStreams.java:50)
at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:37)
at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:29)
at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:21)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at  java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at  java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
at ?.Given I have username and password(Login.feature:4)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final      java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens   java.util" to unnamed module @3551a94
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:177)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:171)
at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields.locate(Fields.java:39)
at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter.<clinit>(TreeMapConverter.java:50)
at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:820)
at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)
at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:530)
at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.<init> (LocalizedXStreams.java:50)
at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:37)
at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:29)
at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
at   cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:21)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

[image]

I have tried with these dependencies to solve this issue,but not worked.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
<version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
<artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
<version>1.4.10-java7</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone getting this error ,please go and check the jre path.It should check the compatible(check with the jdk) path of the jre.This will solve this error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse just do the JDK set up, it will resolve the issue. Windows --> Preference --> Java--> Installed JRE --> Add compatible JDK version and Apply and Close.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30694190)